# UWP и фоновые задачи

Tags: c#, uwp, background-task

Здравствуйте. Может кто подсказать, как сделать так, что бы приложение самостоятельно запускалось при включении компьютера(если пользователь захочет)? При этом значок должен появляться только в списке скрытых значков. При этом юзер может в любой момент открыть приложение в нормальном режиме, а потом закрыть окно приложения и оно перейдет к фоновым задачам.

Я понимаю, что это связано с [этим](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task), но не уверен как это сделать. Есть хорошие примеры по этой теме?

**Обновление**

Если я правильно понял, приложение UWP не может быть добавлено в системный трей. Можно использовать только тайлы. Однако в запуском пока все те же проблемы.